# React js application getting error while deployment to github gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Hi I made simple app with react js however, I don't deploy to github pages.
Normally, Application is running in local but it is not running when I deploy to
github-page. I am getting error in this way when I am looking to console

*bundle.js:26053 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null*

You think,what could be the reason for this

Comment: you've got to find out (by reading the stack track) what the `match` property belongs to.  My guess is that you are missing a dependency in your bundle.

Comment: Can you check, I can't see any missing , https://github.com/onerciller/html-editor

Comment: @DavinTryon I got it this problem, like you said, depencies has been  missing. thank you ;)